# xlwings:change the color of character from Python

Tags: python, colors, character, xlwings

I'm useing xlwings on a Windows.I'd like to change the color of the character input to a cell.But the cord isn't understood.Please give the assistance.Thank you.

Comment: Can you please provide some sample code.

Comment: Sorry.I'd like to know the cord change the color of the  character input to a cell.The character could be put in a cell.

Comment: xw.Range('A1').color = (0,255,0)

Comment: If it's this, the color of the character isn't changed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following should work:

```
import xlwings as xw
wb = xw.books.active
wb.sheets[0]['A1'].font.color = (0, 255, 0)
```

Comment: Thank you for kindly teaching me cord.
I have tested the program and confirmed that it works as expected.
I will do my best with programing study.
I was helped out a lot thanks to you.
Thank you so much.